# How can I pass an array as argument to an R script command line run?

Tags: arrays, r, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to pass an array of hundreds of elements as an argument of an R script via command line in Windows. Firstly, I'd like to declare my array in some way. I'm doing that in command line:

```
set my_array=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...,700)
```

Then I want to run my script and get the array as argument.

```
Rscript my_script my_array
```

But when I try this an error message came up saying that 'the object my_array" could not be found. I know how to get the arguments in my script, using    `args <- commandArgs(TRUE)`. I just need to recognize my declared array as an argument - or declare it in the right way and pass it in the right way as an argument to my script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, i am not sure if you should use `set` to declare any variable in terminal, but you can see more of this on `man set` page.

There are some ways i think you can try to pass an array to R script, it mainly depends on how you declare the `my_array` in terminal.

---

**1 - "my_array" can be a string in bash:**

```
$ my_array="c(0,1,2,3,4)"
$ Rscript my_script ${my_array}
```

And use the `eval(parse(text=()))` in R script to transform the argument as a vector to R environment.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE) 
print(args)
# c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

args <- eval(parse(text=args[1]))
print(args)
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

**2 - "my_array" can be an array in bash:**

```
$ my_array=(0,1,2,3,4)
$ Rscript my_script ${my_array[*]}
```

and in R the `args` is already your array, but of type character:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE) 
print(args)
# [1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do here, let me know if I'm wrong.

I created an R script (called script.R) that contains the following:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
eval(parse(text=args[1]))
print(myarray)
```

I can then call the script like this (from my command line)

```
Rscript script.R myarray="c(1,3,4)"
```

As you can see, the argument gets passed (in your script you could do print(args) to see what gets passed and how), I use eval(parse(text=...))) to make it execute (create myarray in the script) and then I can do what I want with it (in my case, I printed it, but you could do analysis or other stuff).  Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, Joy! But my problem is that I'll have to pass many arrays of hundreds of elements. So if I declare the arrays in the same command line, as in    `Rscript script.R myarray="c(1,3,4)"` I could not declare everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hundreds of values in the array, perhaps it'd more useful to write it to a text file and pass the file path as a parameter and have R read it in.