# How to call R script from command line with multiple augument types (inc. list)

Tags: r, command-line

I have been working on this for a while and I am still stuck.

I would like to call an Rscript using multiple arguments from what is essentially a command line (Snakemake file). The main difference between what I am asking and what I see on SO ([How to pass list of arguments to method in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337937/how-to-pass-list-of-arguments-to-method-in-r), [How can I pass an array as argument to an R script command line run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787627/how-can-i-pass-an-array-as-argument-to-an-r-script-command-line-run), [Is it possible to pass an entire list as a command line argument in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863210/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-entire-list-as-a-command-line-argument-in-r)) is that my arguments are a combination of strings, numbers, **and** a list.

Here is the set up in my rules (Snakemake file):

```
rule cluster_plots_DGE:
   input:
      script = 'src/scripts/create_images_DGE.R',
      analyze_sc_object_output = sc_objects
   params:
      project = PROJECT,
      method = METHOD,
      rpath = RPATH,
      storage=STORAGE,
      components = COMPONENTS,
      reso_file = resolution_file,
      sample_files = integrated_seurat_objects 
   output: dge_files
   log:
      log_output = log_directory + PROJECT.lower() + '_DGE.log'
   shell:
      "Rscript {input.script} {params.project} {params.method} {params.rpath} {params.storage} {params.components} {params.reso_file} {params.sample_files} 2> {log.log_output}"
```

Here is what the call translates to:

```
Rscript src/scripts/create_images_DGE.R project_name ALL path_to_R_installed_libraries rds 50 data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/tables/project_nameR_resolution_list.txt data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_Standard_0.5.RDS data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_RPCA_0.5.RDS data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_SCT_0.5.RDS 2> logs/DGE_Markers/project_name_DGE.log
```

Where `sample_files = integrated_seurat_objects` is a list containing:

```
data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_Standard_0.5.RDS, 
data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_RPCA_0.5.RDS, 
data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_SCT_0.5.RDS
```

And here is the beginning of my R script:

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
compo <- ''
project <- ''
method <- ''
lib_path <- ''
storage <- ''
res_file <- ''
integrated_object <- ''   #list of objects 

# test if there is at least 7 arguments: if not, return an error
if (length(args) < 7) {
  stop('At least seven arguments must be supplied.', call.=FALSE)
} else if (length(args)==7) {
   project = args[1] 
   method = args[2] 
   lib_path = args[3]
   storage = args[4]
   compo = args[5]
   res_file = args[6]
   integrated_object = args[7]
   #integrated_object = eval(parse(text=args[7]))
}

print(compo)
print(project)
print(method)
print(lib_path)
print(storage)
print(res_file)
print(integrated_object)
```

If I use the entire `integrated_seurat_objects` list, this is what gets returned:

```
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
```

If I take the first entry from `integrated_seurat_objects` and pass that as an argument, I get (I have replaced the actual project name and paths is this post):

```
[1] "50"
[1] project_name
[1] "ALL"
[1] library_path_to_R_libraries
[1] "rds"
[1] "data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/tables/project_name_resolution_list.txt"
[1] "data/endpoints/project_name/analysis/PCA_14/RDS/project_name_Standard_0.5.RDS"
```

It seems do-able but I have not cracked it yet. How can I pass multiple arguments that include a list to an R script form the command line? Any assistance is always appreciated.

Comment: You can only pass string values from the command line. Your R script will need to be able to understand how to parse that list of strings into information it needs. If you are passing multiple files, those will be multiple parameters. You don't seem to be handling the case where `length(args)>7`. If the last value is the only one that's variable, just assume that all values after the sixth are files: `integrated_object = args[7:length(args))]`

Comment: @MrFlick --- that is helpful. I have not been able to get it working yet, but I think I am on the right track, thank you. FYI you have an extra ')' in your response.

Comment: I strongly recommend investing some time to learn a command-line parsing package. My favourite for R (and other languages) is [docopt](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=docopt) which I find easy: write the documentation / help string, and it parses the pattern and assign the variables with `opt`.  I have a boatload of usage examples in the [examples/ dir of the littler package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/tree/master/inst/examples).  The main [docopt site](http://docopt.org/) has more (but is not R-specific). And there are alternatives to it on CRAN too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MrFlick deserves credit for this answer. The issue was I was not accounting for a situation where the number of arguments would be greater than 7 (duh).

A quick very fix:

```
if (length(args) < 7) 
{
  stop('At least seven arguments must be supplied.', call.=FALSE)
} 

if (length(args)==7) 
{  
   project = args[1]
   method = args[2] 
   lib_path = args[3]
   storage = args[4]
   compo = args[5]
   res_file = args[6]
   integrated_object = args[7]
}

if (length(args)>7) 
{  
   project = args[1]
   method = args[2] 
   lib_path = args[3]
   storage = args[4]
   compo = args[5]
   res_file = args[6]
   integrated_object = args[7:length(args)]
}
```

Thank you for your eyes @MrFlick